# R - Read multiple csv files from non-working directory into a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a set of .csv files (dataframes) in a folder on my desktop, where the path is:

```
path <- "C:\\User\\Desktop"
```

I would like to read the files into a list, where each element is a dataframe.  I have tried using the following:

```
tp <- list.files(path, pattern = "*.csv")
all_files = lapply(tp, read.delim)
```

The problem is that the above would presuppose my files are in my working directory--i.e. I get an error when I try using my `path`.  I don't want to  put them there.  All of the solutions I have found seem to be based on the files being in the working directory, i.e. they require the use of `setwd()`.  I would simply like to load my files from ANY folder that isn't the working directory.  My questions are:

1. How do I Load my .csv dataframes into a list from a folder that isn't my working directory?  I would also like to maintain the structure of original dataframes--i.e. keep the same number of variables within each dataframe in the list.
2. Why is it so important that the files be in the working directory anyway?

I feel like there are a lot of answers to this question.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to build a path indide the function:

```
tp <- list.files(path, pattern = "*.csv")
all_files <- lapply(tp, function(x) read.delim(file.path(path,x)))
```

Another way is to use full paths:

```
tp <- list.files(path, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
all_files <- lapply(tp, read.delim)
```

Comment: is there a way that would maintain the columns as they are in the original dataframes?  this gives just 1 variable

Comment: @jvalenti I am not sure I follow. What data frame are you referring to? We are dealing with a list of files, and our task is load them into a list.

Comment: The code works well, it just transforms each dataframe in the list into a single df with one variable.  I would like the components in the list to remain the same.

Comment: @jvalenti then you have to tune the parameters of `read.delim`. The separator, perhaps.

Comment: do you mean as in `all-files <- lapply(tp, read.delim(header = T, sep = ","...)`?  I get an error with that

Comment: use `all-files <- lapply(tp, function(x) read.delim(x, header = T, sep = ","))`

Comment: would this not be simpler? `lapply(tp, read.csv, header = T)`?

Comment: @Adam I have no idea what the OP is trying to achieve